# Is array syntax using square brackets in URL query strings valid?

Tags: url, multidimensional-array, query-string

Is it actually safe/valid to use multidimensional array synthax in the URL query string?

```
http://example.com?abc[]=123&abc[]=456
```

It seems to work in every browser and I always thought it was OK to use, but accodring to a comment in this article it is not: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201008/what_characters_are_allowed_unencoded_in_query_strings/#comment4

I would like to hear a second opinion.

Comment: What is "multidimensional" in this? Or are you referring to the get vars being represented as an array in a server side scripting language ?

Comment: @arkascha yep, I mean a query string like this `?a[b][c][d][e]=f`, server side script then treats it like a multidimensional array

Comment: When used judiciously by a **URL dereferencing algorithm**, which is the intent here, that is the intended purpose of reserving the square brackets. You should most definitely *not* use them in a resource name for that very reason -- as referencing algorithms need to use it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The answer is not simple.

The following is extracted from section 3.2.2 of RFC 3986 :

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
> [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
> within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where
> square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.

This *seems* to answer the question by flatly stating that square brackets are not allowed anywhere else in the URI.  But there is a difference between a square bracket character and a percent encoded square bracket character.

The following is extracted from the beginning of section 3 of RFC 3986 :

> 3. Syntax Components
>
> The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
> components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
> fragment.
>
> ```
>   URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
> ```

So the "query" is a component of the "URI".

The following is extracted from section 2.2 of RFC 3986 :

> 2.2.  Reserved Characters
>
> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must
> be percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> ```
>   reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
>   gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
>   sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

So square brackets may appear in a query string, but only if they are percent encoded.  Unless they aren't, to be explained further down in section 2.2 :

> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.  If a reserved character is found in a URI component and
> no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be
> interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
> character's encoding in US-ASCII.

So because square brackets are only allowed in the "host" subcomponent, they "should" be percent encoded in other components and subcomponents, and in this case in the "query" component, unless RFC 3986 explicitly allows unencoded square brackets to represent data in the query component, which it does not.

However, if a "URI producing application" fails to do what it "should" do, by leaving square brackets unencoded in the query, then readers of the URI are not to reject the URI outright.  Instead, the square brackets are to be considered as belonging to the data of the query component, since they are not used as delimiters in that component.

This is why, for example, it is not a violation of RFC 3986 when PHP accepts both unencoded and percent encoded square brackets as valid characters in a query string, and even assigns to them a special purpose.  However, it would appear that authors who try to take advantage of this loophole by not percent encoding square brackets are in violation of RFC 3986.

Comment: "Square brackets can appear in the query string if they are percent encoded, unless they aren't" xD. very nice answer.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but it doesn't account for the WHATWG Url spec. See my answer below.

Comment: This is very well reasoned, but I have to interject. The delimiter character classes do not reserve characters *only, and strictly for the protocol*. **These characters are called
"reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
`implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm`** - Framework, platform and filesystem developers are free to use these with due research. ...

Comment: ... Userland developers are free to incorporate such delimiters into a URL only when passing to such a system with those known properties, as several web frameworks do. You should *not* use delimiters in URL alias names or for any information. They may contain data but not *be* data, as they are delimiters. Some parts of the URL (namely everything before the /path) further restrict delimiter usage. Also notable is the sub-component delimiter `;` is special during the path component for splitting the resource from other metadata `example.com/my; non-routing data/url -> example.com/my/url`

Answer (score 11):

According to RFC 3986, the [Query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) of an URL has the following grammar:

```
*( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

From [appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) of the same RFC:

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
[...]
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG

unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
[...]    
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
             / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

My interpretation of this is that anything that isn't:

```
 ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / 
     "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / 
     "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "=" / ":" / "@"
```

...should be pct-encoded, i.e percent-encoded. Thus `[` and `]` should be percent-encoded to follow RFC 3986.

Comment: You are certainly right, but help me following with that interpretation. The extract you gave is incomplete, 'reserved' is never re-mentioned here. So the definition makes no sense like this. As I read it the square brackets are defined as reserved characters with a special meaning (not sure which), therefore they should not be escaped if you want to express that meaning. If you escape em you  simply transfer a string containing square brackets as value of the  parameter. So I ask myself: well, what _is_ actually the meaning of square brackets being reserved chars in urls?

Comment: I left the definition of `reserved` and `gen-delims` in the quote to make it easier see how `[]` are classified in the grammar - notice that only a subset of `reserved` is a `pchar`.

Comment: Square brackets are reserved for IP v6 address literals. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-D.1, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2732#section-2

Comment: Because an `IPv6` literal applies only to the `host` part `http://[1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A]/index.html`, hence I guess that they don't need to be escaped when used inside a query string

Answer (score 10):

David N. Jafferian's answer is fantastic. I just want to add a couple updates and practical notes:

1. For many years, every browser has left square brackets in query strings unencoded when submitting the request to the server. (Source: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1152455#c6). As such, I imagine a huge portion of the web has come to rely on this behavior, which makes it extremely unlikely to change.
2. My reading of the WHATWG URL standard which, at least for web purposes, can be seen as superseding RFC 3986, is that it codifies this behavior of not encoding `[` and `]` in query strings.

**Edit**: Based on the comments and other answers, a more correct reading of the WHATWG URL standard is that unencoded `[`/`]` *are* invalid, but also should be tolerated when received/parsed and, once parsed that way, should even be re-serialized without encoding.

Comment: Maybe also relevant is WHATWG URL § [Percent-encoded bytes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-bytes). It says square brackets need only be encoded as part of the _userinfo percent-encode set_. That means only in the leading authority component, not in the path, query and fragment components.

Comment: You are right that `query-state` is the relevant portion, however it is the _parsing_ algorithm, so, naturally, it does not make any reference about encoding anything at all. The general step of this state is item 3 in the list, which reads “If c is not a URL code point and not U+0025 (%), validation error”. Since `[` and `]` are _not_ [URL code points](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points), this standard very explicitly prohibits square brackets in URLs.

Comment: @kirelagin That's a very good point that I'm quoting from the parsing section. I mentioned encoding in my answer, though, because the version of the spec at the time actually did specify doing some percent-encoding [_at parse time_](https://github.com/whatwg/url/blob/85d96e253412c2a79b6408bd6e802d9d324ca579/review-drafts/2018-08.bs#L2277). The serialization section of the spec just directly appends the parsed query state as-is, so if an unencoded `[` or `]` can get into the parsed state, then it definitely is legal to serialize unencoded.

Comment: @kirelagin Your point about validation errors though is a good one too, and kinda complicates things. The spec says that validation errors _should not_ terminate the parser. So, running `serialize(parse(urlWithUnencodedQueryBrackets))` would output back the brackets unencoded, I think, but there'd also be a validation error. Make of that what you will, i guess.

Comment: Edit: Well, "then it definitely is legal to serialize unencoded." might be a bit of a stretch. The serialization steps do say to leave the parsed query as-is, but the resulting serialized value would violate the spec's definition of a query string, per the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460012/1261879

Comment: I've just mentioned [this above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490326/is-array-syntax-using-square-brackets-in-url-query-strings-valid/54460012#comment130531010_39294315) , but actually square brackets are indeed not malformed. You should not allow them in resolving generic static file system URLs. If the `implementation-specific URL dereferencing algorithm`, such as a web framework, is designed to accept them this is fine. The characters were reserved for dereferencing algorithm designers -- so framework & file system designers can reliably know URL *names* wont have those characters.

Comment: i.e., If filenames could have square brackets, then it would not be viable for a framework to expose sub-resources within a file because how would you know what they are requesting. The reserved characters separate these sorts of usages -- which is compatible with the array access semantics of this question. The underlying resource is still at `example.com/resource` even if sub resource is exposed at `example.com/resource[0]` but there is no resource name `example.com/my[latest]trip/` because that would make delimiting inviable.

Answer (score 4):

I'd ideally like to comment on [Ethan's answer](http://#answer-49806195) really, but don't have sufficient reputation to do it.

I'm not sure that the relevant part of the WHATWG URL standard is being referenced here. I think the correct part might be in the definition of a valid [URL-query string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-query-string), which it describes as being composed of [URL units](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-units) that themselves are formed from [URL code points](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points) and [percent-encoded bytes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-byte). Square brackets are listed within URL code points and thus fall into the percent-encoded bytes category.

Thus, in answer to the original question, multidimensional array syntax (i.e. using square brackets to represent array indexing) within the query part of the URL is valid, *provided the square brackets are percent encoded* (as %5B for [ and %5D for ]).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding that square brackets are not first-class citizens anyway. Here is the quote:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

> Other characters are unsafe because    gateways and other transport
> agents are known to sometimes modify    such characters. These
> characters are "{", "}", "|", "", "^", "~",    "[", "]", and "`".

Answer (score 1):

I always had a temptation to go for that sort of query when I had to pass an array, but I steered away from it. The reason being:

- It is not cleared defined in RFC.
- Different languages may interpret it differently.

You have a couple of options to pass an array:

- Encode the string representation of the array(JSON may be?)
- Have parameters like "val1=blah&val2=blah&.." or something like that.

And if you are sure about the language you are using, you can (safely) go for the kind of query string you have (Just that you need to %-encode `[]` also).

Comment: So this will be a valid multiarray URL? `?abc%5B%5D=123&abc%5B%5D=456`. Very ugly, I see why it is rarely used

Comment: That would depend on how the language treats it. Its best to stay away from it. To be a bit more precise, they are just key-value pairs. Nothing more, nothing less and there's no "array" in it.