# WebApi FromUri Binding url parameters with braces

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I had an MVC controller with url which had a parameter binding with square braces in it like

```
 public Product GetProduct([Bind(Prefix = "product[productid]") int id)
```

which used to work with the request url like

`http://localhost:8080/Product/GetProduct?product[productid] = 1001`.

I'm able to get the value for `id` as `1001` in MVC  controller. Unfortunately I'm supposed to change this to an web api controller and I have the api controller method defined like this

```
public Task<Product> GetProduct([FromUri(Name=product[productid])] int id)
```

for which i get a 404 response with the same request url . The `[FromUrl]` works with the parameter name without braces when 
defined like

```
public Task<Product> GetProduct([FromUri(Name=productid)] int id)
```

and the url like

`http://localhost:8080/Product/GetProduct?productid = 1001`

Is there any workaround for this apart from parsing the request url with braces and get the value.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490326/is-array-syntax-using-square-brackets-in-url-query-strings-valid) that url is invalid and must be escaped.

Comment: This Is not about dealing with parameterized arrays  it is just about url  the format. The MVC controller works fine with the braces and the WebApi controller doesn't. May be I didn't get it correctly.. Which part should I fix.. The URL or the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is right. You should fix the controller the following way:

```
public Task<Product> GetProduct([FromUri(Name=product.productid)] int id)
```

I don't really know why this works.