# How to make $_GET read the first variable with the same key?

Tags: php, query-string

URL: `http://example.com/?var=foo&var=bar`

How to make PHP set `$_GET['var']` as "foo" and not "bar", without parsing manually `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`? Maybe there is some option in the php.ini file?

Comment: Use a different variable name for the other one or use an array.

Comment: If you don't have control over the URL, your best option is to parse the $_SERVER query string as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately in PHP you cannot do this. You should use an array:

```
http://example.com/?var[]=foo&var[]=bar
```

You will get the following in PHP:

```
$_GET['var'] = ['foo', 'bar']
```

You will find this is different in other languages such a golang where your first example will actually get the same result.

You can find a brilliant answer on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294315/4878850).

Answer (score 0):

No built in way to do this. PHP's `$_GET` wasn't designed for this practice, for it is an uncommon one. I recommend against it.

Comment: actually it should use the first variable and not the last one, like Twitter: https://twitter.com/search?q=foo&q=bar

Answer (score 0):

terrible idea, but i was bored:

```
$url="http://example.com/?var=foo&var=bar";

$x=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); //get the query string

$x=explode('&',$x); //break on &
$x=explode('=',$x[0]); //break on =
echo $x[1]; // =foo
```

Comment: @Barmar and as every one has said that's not possible. I therefore decided to give answer to the spirit of the question which required ignoring that restriction.  I suspect "without manually parsing" is a nice to have, not a must have.

Answer (score 0):

update link to 
`http://localhost/index.php?var[]=foo&var[]=bar`

```
<?php
$foo=$_GET["var"][0];
echo $foo;//foo
print_r($_GET);//full array
?>
```