# C# web API - square-bracket notation in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building a set of web APIs that return data in JSON format. An external app performs an http (GET) request like this:

http://localhost:58807/api/items/search?qualifier=year&sort[0][field]=Year&sort[0][dir]=desc&sort[1][field]=Title&sort[1][dir]=asc

and this is the method which manage the http request:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItems(string qualifier, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> sort)
{
     Does something;
}
```

This is the problem: while the `qualifier` parameter is correctly valued, the `sort` (square-bracket notation in query string) parameter is instead `null`.
What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Filippo

Comment: Have a look at [Is array syntax using square brackets in URL query strings valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490326/is-array-syntax-using-square-brackets-in-url-query-strings-valid) - _"square brackets may appear in a query string, but only if they are percent encoded."_

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the problem? As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Do you mean that `qualifier` is ok, but `sort` is `null`? Do you use ASP.NET Core 2 or it is old ASP.NET?

Comment: Where is your [FromQuery] attribute? Also why enumerable of dictionary? Did you mean just a dictionary? Also don't forget [FromRoute] for the other one

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, sorry, you're right. Yes, the problem is exactly that: at the parameter `qualifier` was correctly assigned the value "year" but the `sort` parameter was null. I use "old" ASP.NET.
The use of binding `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>` was suggested to me in an interesting article on parsing querystring containing arrays with square-bracket notation: [link](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-c-sharp-parse-query-string-get-parameter-arrays-square-bracket-notation-http/)

Comment: @Node.JS There is no any route parameters except `search`. [FromQuery] attribute is not necessary if there is `[ApiController]` attribute. What is the problem with enumerable of dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Web API 2 the binding does not work (using `ApiController` from namespace `System.Web.Http`).

In ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API the binding does work (using `ControllerBase` from namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`).

The difference is in the version.

One way of solution for Web API 2 would be to parse the query:

```
var sortParameters = Request.Query.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("sort"));
var sortFilters = new List<SortFilter>();
foreach (var sortParamter in sortParameters)
{
    sortFilters.Add(ParseSortParameter(sortParameter)); // TODO: implementation of ParseSortParameter
}


public class SortFilter
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

`Request` is of type `HttpRequest`.

Comment: It depends on version of ASP.NET. The OP's code works well in ASP.NET Core