# REST GET Call with List Query Param is not working in POSTMAN

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman, query-string

Calling a REST API that accepts `List` as a Query Param.

Passing Query Param as: `q="Listkey":["listvalue1","Listvalue2"]`

But **Failing** with 400 BAD Request:
`http://localhost:9097/api?q={"caseList":["testlist1"]}`

But **Working** with Query Param passed as below:
`q="Listkey":%5B"listvalue1","Listvalue2"%5D`

`http://localhost:9097/api?q={"caseList":%5B"testlist1"%5D}`

I would like to know why it doesn't work with `[ ]` brackets?

`http://localhost:9097/api?q={"caseList":["testlist1"]}`

Please suggest me best practices of sending `List` Query Param.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

] as this is getting encode as %5D https://www.urlencoder.org/

i belive you will get answer by reading this
[Is array syntax using square brackets in URL query strings valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490326/is-array-syntax-using-square-brackets-in-url-query-strings-valid)