# Map a JavaScript object to query string parameters

Tags: javascript

I need to map a JavaScript object to query string parameters. I found several related questions on this site, but none that fully met my needs.

The object will consist of strings and arrays, but will not be nested. Here is an example:

```
var filters = {
    make: ["Ford", "Honda"],
    year: [],
    color: "Black",
    model: ""
}
```

Here is the code I have:

```
mapQueryStringParameters = function (params) {
    return params
        ? '?' + Object.entries(params)
            .flatMap(([key, value]) => [value].flat().map(v => [key, v]))
            .map(it => it.join("="))
            .join("&")
        : "";
}
```

The above code produces the following result, which is *almost* correct:

```
"?make=Ford&amp;make=Honda&amp;color=Black&amp;model="
```

It correctly omits the `year` empty array, but adds an property for `model`, which is an empty string. How can I modify so that it omits any property with an empty string?

Comment: Shouldn't it be perhaps: `make[]=` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Depends on the server-side language doing the parsing. I think PHP started the fad of adding `[]` to multi-valued entries (see [this answer for more information than anyone could possibly want :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294315/215552))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `flat()` inject this filter

```
.filter(v => v !== "")
```

...and continue with the rest of your chain.

Note that `params` will be truthy when it is just `{}`, so if you don't want to generate the `?` character in that case, you'll need a different logic. Possibly generate the "?" and then remove it if nothing else followed it. Then it will also not generate the "?" when you pass in a non-empty object, but with its properties all set to an empty string:

```js
mapQueryStringParameters = function (params) {
    return ('?' + Object.entries(params)
              .flatMap(([key, value]) => 
                [value].flat()
                       .filter(v => v !== "")
                       .map(v => [key, v]))
                       .map(it => it.join("=")
               )
              .join("&")
          ).replace(/^.$/, "") // Remove lonely "?"
}

var filters = {
    make: ["Ford", "Honda"],
    year: [],
    color: "Black",
    model: ""
}

const query = mapQueryStringParameters(filters);
console.log(query);
```

Comment: Or also `.filter(Boolean)` (***edit***: if you only use strings as values)

Comment: Yes, but then you'll also filter out 0 or `false`, ...

Comment: Indeed, but AFAICS OP's values seem always strings. But yeah. Good notice.

Answer (score 1):

First I would clean the obejct with:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  if (obj[key] === '' || obj[key].length === 0) {
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
```

Then build the URL with:

```
const obj = {
  make: 'Nissan',
  color: ['yellow', 'orange', 'blue'],
};

const result = '?' + new URLSearchParams(obj).toString();
console.log(result); // ️ '?make=Nissan&color=yellow%2Corange%2Cblue'
```

Comment: But that's not the output they want for arrays with multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter first and then get the string.

```js
const
    filters = { make: ["Ford", "Honda"], year: [], color: "Black", model: "" },
    temp = Object
        .entries(filters)
        .filter(([, v]) => v !== '')
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => [].concat(v).map(e => `${k}=${e}`))
        .join('&'),
    result = (temp && '?') + temp;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Except query strings are delimited by `&` characters, not `;`. and the initial character should be `?`.